# Does WordPress MultiSite use separate MySql databases?

Tags: multisite, database, options, configuration

I ask because I cannot find the options from a plug-in I created on my second blog.

Adding this plug-in to the main site and the options show up.

I am confused because there is a column in **wp_options** table **blog_id** and I was expecting there to be more than one value there.

Comment: Is this telling me it does? http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WordPress MU uses one database and each blog gets his own tables with the blog id in the prefix, so once you install a network installation your database should have these tables:

- wp_1_categories
- wp_1_comments
- wp_1_link2cat
- wp_1_links
- wp_1_options
- wp_1_post2cat
- wp_1_postmeta
- wp_1_posts
- wp_blogs
- wp_blog_versions
- wp_registration_log
- wp_signups
- wp_site
- wp_sitecategories
- wp_sitemeta
- wp_usermeta
- wp_users

And every new site you set up will create separate tables for example:

- wp_2_categories
- wp_2_comments
- wp_2_link2cat
- wp_2_links
- wp_2_options
- wp_2_post2cat
- wp_2_postmeta
- wp_2_posts

Comment: Ok thanks. Just spoken to our Server admin and he has set up a separate database. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 3):

Although WordPress MU requires just a single database, as seen on [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), you can always use different databases if you prefer to.

Plugins such as [Multi-DB](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-db) allow you to do so, and although this wouldn't be much needed for a small-medium network, it would be interesting for large setups.

Comment: I think this is what we did because of problems with 'wordpressmu' appearing in permalinks. My DBA has given me the login for the second database now. Thanks for the help.